# Accessing list from variation

Tags: list, query, variations, spcontext

I retrieve all the lists in the current web using:

```
foreach (SPList list in SPContext.Current.Web.Lists) 
{}
```

This works well. The problem is that when a user changes languages, and is routed to the variation, for example:

```
en-US/Site1/Page1.aspx to 
fr-FR/Site1/Page1.aspx
```

the 'foreach' loop looks in the 'fr-FR/Site1' for the lists instead of 'en-US/Site1'.

How can I always make sure I am looking in the 'en-US' variation of any site for a list of all lists?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list which you want to use for all variations it would be better to place that at the root site instead of at the site of one of the variations.

But if it's in a web part (or other control) running in the context of one of the sites in one of the variations you can use the following to find your lists.

[`Variations.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.variations.current%28v=office.14%29.aspx) will give you the current Variations object.

[`Variations.UserAccessibleLabels`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.variations.useraccessiblelabels%28v=office.14%29.aspx) on that object will then give you a list of [`VariationLabel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.variationlabel%28v=office.14%29.aspx) objects.

When looping through the `VariationLabel` objects you can check one of the properties like `Title`, `IsSource`, `Locale` or `Language` to find the `VariationLabel` where you have your lists.

Finally you can use the [`VariationLabel.TopWebUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.variationlabel.topweburl%28v=office.14%29.aspx) of that `VariationLabel` to get the SPWeb and then the lists.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This seems like what I'm looking for, I will make an attempt and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, 2 nice article to read [Stefan Goßner's Variations Guide](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2011/11/21/sharepoint-variations-the-complete-guide-part-6-configuration-internals.aspx), and a [Waldek Mastykarz](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-provisioning-variations-in-sharepoint-server-2010/). You need to,first, locate another(en-Us) site collection, and, second - get the righ list. Variations Labels list (`site.RootWeb.List[site.RootWeb.AllProperties["_VarLabelsListId"]]`) helps you locate the en-Us url of the target site collection to work with.